# Errors on webapp deploying in Jetty

Tags: servlets, jetty

I have those problems with a webapp.Can you help me, please? :)

First error:

2012-03-15 09:51:57.023:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for NAME_OF_WEBAPP/NAME_OF_SERVLET

This request comes from a form contained in an html page.
After this error, the terminal shows me this error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/payloads/PayloadEncoder
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:369)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:390)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.create(AbstractPluginLoader.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:835)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.access$100(IndexSchema.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:429)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:456)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:520)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at connector.SolrConnector.<init>(SolrConnector.java:33)
    at connector.SolrConnector.getInstance(SolrConnector.java:69)
    at connector.SolrConnector.getSolrServer(SolrConnector.java:77)
    at connector.QueryServlet.doGet(QueryServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadEncoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:369)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:390)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.create(AbstractPluginLoader.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:835)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.access$100(IndexSchema.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:429)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:456)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:520)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at connector.SolrConnector.<init>(SolrConnector.java:33)
    at connector.SolrConnector.getInstance(SolrConnector.java:69)
    at connector.SolrConnector.getSolrServer(SolrConnector.java:77)
    at connector.QueryServlet.doGet(QueryServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I compile the file WAR, there aren't errors.. 
I use Jetty 7.6.0.RC4, Solr 1.4.1 and Java 7.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadEncoder

This is rather self-explaining. The mentioned class cannot be found in the runtime classpath.

Make sure that the mentioned class (or at least, the JAR file containing the class) is in the runtime classpath of the webapp. One of the folders covered by the webapp's default runtime classpath is the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Drop the necessary JARs in there.

As the package name hints, that class is part of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) library. If you need to, you can just download it from over there.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I'll try to put the necessary jar in /lib folder and re-build the WAR file.

Comment: I solve the problem too! woth jetty 7.6.10.v20130312